# Changing button onclick to load an animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to add a gif loading onclick or to delete "changing text on click" with an animation with the same button characteristics and a gif overlayed (eg. Searchbox from airbnb.com) How can i do it?

Thank you!

```
<input onclick="change()" type="submit" class="submit-form" value="Log in" id="myButton1">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() 
        document.getElementById("myButton1").value = "Logging in..."; 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

try with this below code which is having loading image and text as well.

```js
$('#myButton1').click(function(){
      $('#myButton1').hide();
      $('.load').addClass('loading');
        setTimeout(function () { 
        $('.load').removeClass('loading');
        $('#myButton1').show();

      }, 2000);
    });
```

```css
.loading{
  background-image : url('http://www.fotos-lienzo.es/media/aw_searchautocomplete/default/loading.gif');  
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.loading:after {
    content: "Logging in...";
    text-align : right;
    padding-left : 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input   type="submit" class="submit-form" value="Log in" id="myButton1">
    <div class="load"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {
        document.getElementById("myButton1").style.background='#000000'; 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your question tags you using JQuery

```
    function change() 
     $("#myButton1").css({
       background-image:url('PATH/TO/LOADING/IMAGE.gif')
     }); 
    }
```

and after finish loading you can create a function to stop loading

```
function stopLoading() 
     $("#myButton1").css({
       background-image:'none'
     }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the image, it's background is not transparent. I just hope atleast it will give you an idea.

https://jsfiddle.net/3pmpqpwj/

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <img src='http://www.arabianbusiness.com/skins/ab.main/gfx/loading_spinner.gif' id='overlay' style="display:none;" />
        <button id="searchbtn" class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="change(); alert('test');">Log In</button>
```

CSS

```
#overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 2px;
    z-index: 3;
    left: 32px;
}
```

JS

```
$('#searchbtn').click(function(){
     $(this).html("Logging in...").prop('disabled',true); 
     $("#overlay").show();
});
```

Comment: It does not work.

                    <div class="line">
                        <input onclick="change()" type="submit" class="submit-form" value="<?= Yii::t('app', 'Access your account') ?>" id="myButton1">

<script type="text/javascript">
function change()
{
    document.getElementById("myButton1").value="Logging in..."; 
}
</script>        

I've introduced the CSS class in style.css, and js&html in .php file. It does not work!

Comment: How it doesn't work? Did you include the jquery library? Did you link the CSS? Because as you can see it works in jsfiddle. Or do you mean in 'It does not work' is the output in jsfiddle I posted is not what you're looking for?